# No module named 'bs4' Error

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I planned to do web scraping, but I seem to be stuck on very first step.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import beautifulSoup

wiki = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_state_and_union_territory_capitals_in_India"

page = urllib.urlopen(wiki)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

print(soup.prettify())
```

I wrote these line just to test, but it shows an error that

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/python programs/Web Scraping/wiki.py", line 3, in <module>
    from bs4 import beautifulSoup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Things which i tried to clear it.

1) pip install beautifulsoup4 (tried this with easy_install as well)

2) check the python path in environment variable. i have included both C:\python and C:\python\Scripts in paths.

3) Tried downloading Beautiful Soup from crummy.com and then install from `python setup.py install command.

I spent almost whole day clearing this out, tried almost every solution and its literally frustrating now. but if anyone still wants to mark it as duplicate you are free to do so.

is there anything i have missed ?

Comment: You're using Windows. Please see https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ for a suitable version of BeautifulSoup.

Comment: When you retrieve the file use `pip install <name of file>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't really see a clear way to answer your question with the information you provided, but it seems that you are not installing the bs4 package properly...

--Easy Way to Fix--

Install PyCharm:
https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=windows

Once installed, configure your interpreter to use latest version of Python (install from here):
https://www.python.org/downloads/

Once you have your file open, click "File > Settings > Project Interpreter > Show All (in the drop down) > Add(+) > Add Local" and select your installed version Python. Then click the add button (+) and search for bs4 from the list of packages and install it, and you should get it working. PyCharm does everything for you, so there is really no room for error when installing packages.

Comment: My problem was solved after upgrading virtualenv (pip install -U virtualenv). BeautifulSoup4 requires pip version 18, but you can't get pip version 18 unless you upgrade virtualenv. The same was true for PyCharm as well. The import was failing in PyCHarm until i upgraded pip in PyCharm.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for those of us not using an IDE (I am using Notepad++ in Windows and came across the same issue). Here is how to fix it in the Windows cmd line:

1. make sure you are running pip version 18.1:

> Py -3 -m pip install --upgrade pip

2. Install BeautifulSoup4 *specifically* for Python 3:

> Py -3 -m pip install beautifulsoup4

The error you are encountering usually occurs if you have both Python 2 and Python 3 on your system.

Usually, your system will default to installing bs4 for Python 2 (which is incompatible with the bs4 package) and you will get the error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'

...since it is looking for the module in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see what version of python are you running (e.g. 3.8.0...) and then select the correspondent python interpreter for your IDE. Note: It does matter if you are running a project under your virtualenvs.